# Looping a value into a list (changing value)

Tags: python, list, loops

Im trying to produce a list with 360 values, determined by the formula provided. I keep getting a syntax error on the "Elist" portion highlighted. This is using python 3.4.

```
SRate = [5,5,5]    
Bots = 120
NQueue = 3
TSim = 100
Exp = 2
DDistance = 1
Lambda = 40 # 120/3 = 40

import random

AvgSRate = 5

def Initilization(AvgSRate,Lambda,Exp,x):
    Elist = []
    for a in range(1,361):
        x = (Lambda/(AvgSRate**Exp))*(1+(1/10)*(2*(random.random()) - 1)
        Elist.append(x) # <--- Error is in this line.
    return Expectation_list
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a closing paren:

```
x = (Lambda/(AvgSRate**Exp))*(1+(1/10)*(2*(random.random()) - 1)  <-
```

Just add a closing paren and your error will be gone:

```
x = (Lambda/(AvgSRate**Exp))*(1+(1/10)*(2*(random.random()) - 1))
```

Make sure `Expectation_list` is also defined somewhere or more likely you should be returning  `Elist`.

You are reassigning x also so you don't actually ever use the parameter `x` passed in so remove it if you are not using it, if you just want to return Elist then you can return a list comp:

```
def Initilization(AvgSRate, Lambda, Exp):
return [(Lambda / (AvgSRate ** Exp)) * (1 + (1 / 10) * (2 * (random.random()) - 1))
        for a in range(1, 361)]
```